# Outlook inbox data into ListView

Tags: vb.net

I am using this below code to pull the details from outlook inbox into vb.net list view.  Somehow, the data is not populating properly (see attached image). Also, I am not able to see headers for the list view. Can someone help me on this.

```
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' Get Messages collection of Inbox.
Dim oInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items = oInbox.Items

oItems = oItems '.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
'  Console.WriteLine("Total Unread : " & oItems.Count) ' Get unread e-mail messages.

Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To oItems.Count
    'Test to make sure item is a mail item and not a meeting request.
    If oItems.Item(i).MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then

        oMsg = oItems.Item(i)
        Dim msgStr(3) As String
        msgStr(0) = oMsg.ReceivedTime
        msgStr(1) = oMsg.SenderName
        msgStr(2) = oMsg.Subject
        Dim lstViewItem As New ListViewItem(msgStr)
        'lstViewItem.Tag = oMsg.Body

        ListView2.Items.Add(lstViewItem)
    End If
Next
oApp = Nothing
oNS = Nothing
oItems = Nothing
oMsg = Nothing
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see columns and column headers you need to set the `View` property of the `ListView` to `Details` and create columns, for instance like this:

```
    With Me.ListViewMails
        .Columns.Add("ReceivedTime", 100)
        .Columns.Add("Sender", 100)
        .Columns.Add("Subject", 300)
    End With
```

To put your mail info inside the separate columns you can do something like this:

```
    Dim item As ListViewItem
    item = Me.ListViewMails.Items.Add("2018-01-07")   'main column, usually the first one
    item.SubItems.Add("John Doe")   'second column
    item.SubItems.Add("This is my very own subject")   'third column
```

You need to play around with the several overloads of the `Add` functions to get what you want.